# Execve not executing process

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a basic shell using C++.

This is part of a homework assignment so I have some constraints I need to follow.

Here is how I have things set up now:

- `argv` contains the process name and its arguments
- I fork the current process
- I read the process name and the arguments, and I print them out
- I wait for the child process to complete
- I print "finished" to let me know that the parent process has finished.

This is my code:

```
void simple_shell::exec_command(char **argv){
  // TODO: fork a child process to execute the command.
  // parent process should wait for the child process to complete and reap it
  int rc = fork();
  if (rc < 0) {
      cout << "Fork failed" << endl;
      exit(1);
  } else if (rc == 0) { // child process
      cout << "child process running" << endl;
      char *processName = argv[0];
      cout << processName << endl;
      char *argument1 = argv[1];
      cout << argument1 << endl;
      execvp(processName, argv);
  } else {
      wait(NULL);
      cout << "finished" << endl;
  }
}
```

When I run the shell, I write "hello world", and here is what I get printed:

> child process running
>   hello
>   world

So basically, the fork is successful, the child process runs, and the arguments are passed in correctly (as shown by the printing of hello world). However, the parent process never prints "finished".

Secondly, when I pass in an actual process name of a process that exists in the same directory where I am executing the shell from, the process never runs. I just get the name of the process printed out.

I'm very confused as to why I am getting this behavior.

Comment: `if(...) { ... std::cout << "child process running"; ... } else { std::cout << "finished";}` how could you possibly expect that "**child process running**" and "**finished**" are both going to be printed at some point..?

Comment: I'm forking the process, so this should work, right?

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations This is fine, and Fureeish is incorrect. You get the first printed in the child and the second in the parent after the wait() call returns (assuming no other errors in the code).

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations You realize that by setting `processName = argv[0]` and then calling `execvp`, you're running the *current* process again, right?

Comment: @bnaecker I think you're confusing this argv with the one that is passed into the main function.

Comment: You are very confused because you made the classical mistake of assuming that the system call is guaranteed to work, 100% of the time. `execvp()` can fail, just like any other system call. If you were to check its return value (which must be an error, since a successful `exec()` never returns), and interrogate what's in `errno`, this will likely give you a honking clue as to what's wrong. P.S. -- your `argv` is null pointer terminated, right?

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations Ah, yep, I thought this was in `main()`.

Comment: "name of a process that exists in the same directory" - you mean name of an executable file? Are you passing it as something like "myexe" or "./myexe"?